# Ajax отправка переменной js на php

Tags: php, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу отправить информацию которую не должен увидеть клиент с помощью Ajax на сервер php. Например нужно отправить на сервер id сообщения, для его удаления. Проверка на сервере есть максимальная, которую можно сделать на сервере, а вот id комментария находиться в переменной js, которую в дальнейшем можно получить. Какие есть варианты сделать такой запрос?

Comment: Что такое " безопасного использования выполнения ajax запроса" ?

Comment: Типо того, что бы не злоупотреблять одной функцией, и не удалять сообщения id которых не равны нажатия кнопки удалить